# Overflow not working on my website

Tags: css, html

On my website, I have basically something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d5Mg4/1/.

The problem is, that while in this fiddle everything works as intended, on my website it does not work.

I know that you guys don't like direct links to websites and I know that this is a website in foreign language, but I don't know what else can I do!

Here is the link to the page: https://scyk.pl/Forums/Thread/Informatyka/5#post41.

The problem is with that gray box (the `<code>` block), as you can see, there is a lot of text in it, it has the `overflow` property set to `auto`, and it has `display` property set to `block`. I even tried using `height` and `width` properties, but only result I get is the `overflow-y` scrollbar, and I need both of them (expecially `overflow-x` one).

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @David: ff and chrome

Comment: @IanBrindley: Scroll is not working either

Comment: Set a width and height along with overflow: auto. I have tried this with firebug and it works...

Comment: @IanBrindley: I did this in firebug and I only get vertical scrollbar, not the horizontal one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works on the Fiddle because the "text" is all one word and can't be broken (without `word-break:break-all`), wheras in your live example there are words to be wrapped.

Try adding `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: Hm. Wait a sec, in ff this works, need to look at that closier.

Comment: It looks like you need to set a `width` as well.